# recursive strcpy function

Tags: c, string, recursion, strcpy

```
#include <stdio.h>
char *strcpy_r(char* s, char* t);

int main()
{
  char *s = {"Bob"};
  char *t = {"Billy"};
  char *ptr;
  ptr = strcpy_r(s, t);
  printf("%s\n", ptr);

  return 0;
}

char* strcpy_r(char* s, char* t)
{
  if((*s = *t) != '\0')
    strcpy_r(s + 1, t + 1);
  return s;
}
```

I'm just doing this for practice, but when I compiled it. I got a seg fault from main. Could someone tell me what might've caused this seg fault?

Comment: `{"Billy")` is this a typo?

Comment: You're trying to modify a string literal. That is undefined behaviour and often crashes.

Comment: Yeah sorry that is a typo. I'll fix that now.

Comment: Also your example would run into "problems" after the 4th recursive call, as then `*s` is dereferencing memory not allocated to the inital pointer `s`. Your code would only work for `t` not being shorter then `s`.

Comment: Would my recursive function work outside of this context? My main focus was to write a working strcpy function recursively.

Comment: As long as the string `t`referrs to isn't to larger, so that recursing down into `strcpy_r()` won't eat up all the apps stack, it works.

Answer (score 3):

Congratulations, you have invoked undefined behavior **twice within one line.**

First, you can't modify the contents of a string literal. So `strcpy()`ing onto `"foo"` is wrong.

Two, even if you could: you're copying a string to a buffer that is shorter than the string. This is UB again.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to modify a constant string. This is wrong! Chances of segfault live when you modify a constant string.

Instead do this:

```
  char s[10] = "Bob";
  char t[10] = "Billy";
  char *ptr;
```

Comment: Voted up as that's indeed the first problem, although with that change they'll immediately hit the second problem: `s` doesn't have as much storage as `t`, so the copy will write past the end of the buffer.

Comment: @H2CO3 thanks - I've modified the program

Answer (score 0):

You can't overwrite the memory that's used to hold a quoted string. That'll segfault instantly.

Answer (score 0):

String literals are *constant*, i.e. they cant change. You're also trying to copy a longer string into a shorter string, which will write beyond the bounds of the destination string.

Both of these problems leads to *undefined behavior* which can cause a crash.

---

To solve the first problem, you have to use an array for the destination string. To solve the other problem, you have to make sure the destination array is *at least* as large as the source string (including its terminating `'\0'`).

Comment: I see. Would my recursive function work for those that are not string literals? My main focus was to write a valid strcpy function recursively.

Comment: @Bonnie Only the destination needs to be an array.